# Pandas concatenate Previous Current and Next text

Tags: python, pandas

Given the input data frame

```
Event_id,reportTime,ReportValX,ReportValY,ReportText

1,13_01,13,1,Man Arrived near the car
1,13_02,13,2.2,The Car was fast
1,13_02,13,2.1,The lights were on.
1,13_03,13,3,The man hit the car
2,13_01,13,1,Cat was on the mat
2,13_02,13,2.2,mat was red
2,13_03,13,3.1,Dad is a man
2,13_03,13,3,Dad has a hat
```

[image]

**Description**

For a Given Event ID, as in examples we have 1 & 2 events.
For each event there is a Time of report 13_01. 13 is Hour and 01 is minute.
For Each report there are two numeric values ReportValX,ReportValY , and a Report Text eg ",Man Arrived near the car".
For a given Event id, at given time eg 13_02 there may be multiple reports.
eg: Event ID 1, time 13_02  and Event ID 2 time 13_03.

**Challenge**
For Every Hour in an Event ID, collect the previous Text, current Text, other Text which has the Same time Seperated by tag  , and the Following Text of the Hour separated by Text

eg:

```
Event_id,reportTime,ReportValX,ReportValY,ReportText_Before,Reprt Text_Current,Report Text Same Time,Report Text Later

1,13_01,13,1,,Man Arrived near the car,Man Arrived near the car,The Car was fast. <NEXT> The lights were on. <NEXT> The man hit the car
1,13_02,13,2.2,Man Arrived near the car,The Car was fast,The Car was fast <NEXT> The lights were on.,The man hit the car
```

**Rules**

1. Event_id,reportTime,ReportValX,ReportValY, is As is.
2. ReportText_Before:  When Time in 13_4 .. All the Text for 13_1 +<
   Next> + 13_02 +  + .. <13_4>
3. ReportText_Reprt Text_Current: 
   The Text at 13_4
4. ReportText_Reprt Report Text Same Time:  All the
   Text which happened at the same time,13_4 Seperated by tag .
5. Report Text Later: All the text 13_05 + + 13_06 + ..... 13_N.

[image]

Input and output are also provided as images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play a bit with [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to achieve what you want.

First, create two new column `'Hour'` and `'Minute'` to identify time more easily.

```
df["Hour"], df["Minute"] = zip(*df['reportTime'].apply(lambda x : list(map(int, x.split('_')))))
```

Then write a custom function to make the new column and use `groupby` and `apply` to use it.

```
def makerep(x):
    res = x[['Event_id','reportTime','ReportValX','ReportValY']]
    res['ReportText_Before'] = x.apply(lambda el : '<NEXT>'.join(x['ReportText'].loc[x['Minute'] < el['Minute']]), axis=1)
    res['ReportText_Current'] = x['ReportText']
    res['ReportText_SameTime'] = x.apply(lambda el : '<NEXT>'.join(x['ReportText'].loc[x['Minute'] == el['Minute']]), axis=1)
    res['ReportText_Later'] = x.apply(lambda el : '<NEXT>'.join(x['ReportText'].loc[x['Minute'] > el['Minute']]), axis=1)
    return res

ddf = df.groupby(['Event_id', 'Hour']).apply(makerep)
```

You can group on `'Event_id'` and `'Hour'`, and use `'Minute'` to select earlier, same or later minutes when concatenating the strings in the new columns.